# I require assistance in proving this language as not regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that L = {$0^n1^m0^n | m,n >= 1$} in NOT regular but I am struggling with the demostration process.

I know the conditions are that:

- $|y| > 0$; $'y'$ can't be empty
- $|xy| <= p$(word/string length)
- for all $i$ > 0, $xy^iz$ must be in L

Lets choose the string $s = 0^p10^p$.

The first condition states that: $y = 0^k$ for $k > 0$

Being $x$ and $y$ composed of zeros such that complies with the second condition.

At $i = 0$, the string should be in L, thus $xy^0z = xz = 0^{p-k}10^p$ but $y$ can't be empty, right?

**From now on, I get lost in the demostration and require help to properly prove it is not regular.**

Comment: If $p$ is the pumping length, then splitting the string $w=0^p10^p$ as per the pumping lemma must have $y \in 0^+$, and thus $z$ must be a finite suffix of the form $0^*10^p$. But then $w_i = xy^iz$ has a longer $0$-prefix than $0$-suffix when $i \geq 2$, creating a contradiction as all $w_i$ are supposed to be in $L$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the empty pump matters (in fact, sometimes the empty pump, e.g.
the case $i=0$ is the simplest way to prove the non-regularity). Thus, the third condition is actually *"for all $i\geq 0$ $x y^i z\in L$"*. The condition *"$y$ can't be empty"* is not about the iterations number (e.g. the string $y^i$), it states that the word $y$ itself is not empty. Otherwise, every language is trivially pumped if we choose $y=\varepsilon$ and the lemma is meaningless.

Thus, your proof is correct, using the empty pump. If you do not like the case $i=0$, you may choose $i=2$ and get another word $0^{p+k}10^p\notin L$, but imo your choice is nice enough.

The only imprecise part is about the order of the applications of 1st and 2nd conditions. If you do not apply the condition $|xy|\leq p$ to the word $0^p 1 0^p$, you cannot know in advance that $y$ consists of zeros. There are many non-empty subwords of $0^p 1 0^p$ containing also $1$. The condition $|y|>0$ determines that $y=0^{k}$, $k>0$ only after the second condition determines that $y\in 0^*$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask for an example/elaboration on how for each i, the word has the same number of 0s and 1s? Thus demonstrating that contradicts due to y>=1?. Sorry to bother if I ask too much. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @BadProgrammer I cannot see from the description of your language that the number of 1 and 0 must be equal or unequal. The only condition is that the number of zeros before 1 is the same as the number of zeros after 1. Thus, $0^{p+i*k}10^p$ is not in $L$ for all $i\neq 0$ (e.g., for all $y^j$, where $j\neq 1$). The pump throws us out of the language, and since all regular languages can be pumped, this language is not regular.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Apologies, I am pretty new to this subject matter. Thanks